# use package's config files in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, package, config

I have a laravel 5 package based application.In the package this is my structure:

```
Packages
       -vendor
             -xxx
                 -public
                 -src
                     -config
                           -config.php
                     -Vendor
                          -Xxx
                             -Controllers
                             -Models
                             -Repositories
                             XxxServiceProvider.php
                 -views
                 routes.php
```

** The above is my package structure : xxx is the package name.

In this config/config.php  i have the configs i use in this package.

How can i access this config file to use the values in it?

I added the following code in  XxxServiceProvider.php

```
$this->publishes([   __DIR__.'/xxx/src/config/config.php'=>config_path('xxx/config.php'),
             ]);
```

and php artisan vendor:publish , it gave the following error:
Can't locate path:

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Your package structure is not clear. Probably your package config path is the one throwing that error. Check if the specified path is correct.
You can access your package configuration using `Config::get('package::file.option');` or if you have published then you can access it like `Config::get('file.option');`

Answer (score 4):

If your package structure is like the one below then you can load your package's config file like so. Try customizing it for your own structure.

```
/xxx
    |_ /src
        |_ /Config
            - xxx.php
        - XxxServiceProvider.php
```

Add to `XxxServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot() {

    // Allow your user to publish the config
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/Config/xxx.php' => config_path('xxx.php'),
    ], 'config');

}


public function register() {

    // Load the config file and merge it with the user's (should it get published)
    $this->mergeConfigFrom( __DIR__.'/Config/xxx.php', 'xxx');
}
```